# conditional dropdown's using jQuery in contact form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to create a conditional dropdown. I have two dropdowns: 1st is course & 2nd is location. But some courses are not available for some location. So I want to hide that location for that course selection.

```html
<p>[select course-interested "Certified Design Engineer " "Certified CAD Engineer " "Certified CAD Professional " "Certified Basic CAD Modeler " "Workshop in 2D CAD and 3D CAD" "Certified Proficiency Workshop" "Proficiency Workshop In AutoCAD 2D+3D" "Pro-3D Visualization" "Pro-Architect" "Pro-Civil Engineer" "Pro- Interior Designer" "Corporate Training"]</p>
<p>[select* location "Dhankawadi" "Kothrud" "Chinchwad" "Hadapsar" "Baramati" "Nagar Road" "Nagpur"] </p>
```

So please suggest any solution using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone suggest me this solution is correct or wrong.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#course").val("Certified Design Engineer").change(function()
  {
       $("#location").val("Dhankawadi").show();
       $("#location").val("Kothrud").hide();
       $("#location").val("Chinchwad").hide();
       $("#location").val("Hadapsar").hide();
       $("#location").val("Baramati").hide();
       $("#location").val("Nagar Road").hide();
       $("#location").val("Nagpur").hide();
 });
});
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#course').change(function(){
  /*Here your spectific condition*/
  
 if($("#course option:selected").val()=="1" ||$("#course option:selected").val()=="3"){
 $('#location #location_1').show()
 $('#location #location_3').show()
 $('#location #location_2').hide()
 }
  else
    {
    $('#location #location_2').show()
      
    }
   
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="course"><option value="0">Select</option><option value="1">B.com</option><option value="2">B.Sc.</option><option value="3">B.A.</option></select>

<select id="location" ><option value="1" id="location_1">Mumbai</option><option value="2" id="location_2">NaviMumbai</option><option value="3" id="location_3" >Dhule</option></select>
```

Comment: But i want to hide particular option/location

Comment: I'm not able to give id to the dropdown options in contact form 7 wordpress plugin. suggest any other solutions

Comment: are you getting values of location from database. if yes then on change you should pull value from the database using ajax call and then remove all option from location and bind it this should be your logic. using this it will become dynamic and can able to handle future changes.